# Alamofire fire variable type has no subscript members

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swift3

After updating to Alamofire 4 and updating my code to Swift 3, all of my requests are not working for some reason. The variables that I am trying to utilize are highlighted in red and say "Type Any' has no subscript members"

Here is my code:

```
    Alamofire.request("https://example.com/notifications.php?action=\(action)&UUID=\(UniversalUUID)&token=\(token)").responseJSON{ (response) -> Void in

      if let JSON = response.result.value{
     let message = JSON["message"] as! String

    print(message)

}
```

Answer (score 15):

You need to add `as? [String: Any]`

```
Alamofire.request(yourURL).responseJSON { (response) in
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            if let JSON = response.result.value as? [String: Any] {
                let message = JSON["message"] as! String
                print(message)
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            // error handling
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I had similar problem, for me solution was to change it as below

```
let urladdress = "https://api.github.com/users"
Alamofire.request(urladdress).responseJSON(completionHandler: {
    response in
    print(response)
})
```