# "Type 'Any' has no subscript members" error on Alamofire 4.0

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I am using `Alamofire 4.0` with `Swift 3.0` and I am using the following code to parse the `JSON`:

```
Alamofire.request(url!, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

    switch(response.result) {
        case .success(_):
            if let JSON = response.result.value{
                print(JSON)
                //print(JSON["name"])
                //print(JSON["age"])
            }
            break

        case .failure(_):
            print("There is an error")
            break
    }
}
```

And it gives me the following response:

```
(
    {
        Name = "Peter";
        Age = "18";
    }
)
```

The problem is that I could not access to that values (`Name` and `Age`) because when I try to do `JSON["name"]` I am getting the following error:

> Type 'Any' has no subscript members

I also have tried adding `as? [String: Any]` as this question suggest: [Alamofire fire variable type has no subscript members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39502357/alamofire-fire-variable-type-has-no-subscript-members) and this other one also suggest: [Type Any has no subscript members Error in Swift 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39553834/type-any-has-no-subscript-members-error-in-swift-3-0) but any response is giving to me when I use it.

If I use:

```
case .success(_):
    if let JSON = response.result.value as? [String: Any]{
          print(JSON)
          print(JSON["TitularEmail"] as! String)
     }
     break
```

No errors are shown neither in `Xcode` or in the console of Xcode. Instead, no response is given.

How can I solve this error on a proper way? It is ok, with the solution before I am not getting any error but I am not getting any response also so it does not fix it at all.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your JSON is seem tobe an Array, not Dictionary. So try as? [[String: Any]] not as? [String: Any]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try below code:**

```
Alamofire.request(url!, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { response in

switch(response.result) {
    case .success(_):
        if let JSON = response.result.value as! [[String : Any]]!{
                print("JSON: \(JSON)")
                let dic = JSON[0] as [String:AnyObject]!
                print("TitularEmail : ",dic?["TitularEmail"])
            }
        break

    case .failure(_):
        print("There is an error")
        break
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it is giving to me the same behaviour. No errors and no responses on the console.

Comment: Are you able to print JSON?

Comment: No, when I try to cast it, I am not able to print JSON. When I do not cast it, I can print it perfectly.

Comment: Check my updated answer. Because your response is in array that's why you need to typa cast in "[[String : Any]]" as @A Bào said.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is very close. Now I am getting `TitularEmail :  Optional(Peter)`. How can I get the text inside of it? I tried `dic?["TitularEmail"].text` but it gives to me `nil` value.

Comment: @Error404 Thats Gud :)